# Accessing external ip from internal network does not work for port 443 but works for 80

Tags: router, port-forwarding, https

I have the below setup

```
RPI <===> Router <===> internet
```

I port forwarded port 80 and 443 in the router so that the web server running in rpi is accessible outside. I was able to access the web server from both from internal network and external network just fine. DNS is pointing to the external IP.
Recently in the past few weeks, the web server is not working from the internal network but working fine from outside. I have no idea what changed. Nothing in the router or the RPI changed anything except for automatic system updates. However connecting to a different port works fine. To summarize the problem:

```
 curl -v -L http://example.com
*   Trying ext.ip.xx.xx:80...
* Connected to example.com (ext.ip.xx.xx) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: example.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.74.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 308 Permanent Redirect
< Connection: close
< Location: https://example.com/
< Server: Caddy
< Date: Mon, 21 Mar 2022 04:32:02 GMT
< Content-Length: 0
< 
* Closing connection 0
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://example.com/'
*   Trying ext.ip.xx.xx:443...
^C
```

Things I tried so far:

1. Restarted the router
2. Removed and re-added port forwarding rules
3. Tried forwarding different port 8443. Works fine like 80
4. Tried forwarding to a different computer which runs a different distro (arch). Works for all ports except 443
5. Tried to access the web server from outside (vps). Works fine on all ports including 443

Any clue how to debug this further?

Comment: What happens if you try to access the webserver through it's private IP instead of it's public IP from within the "internal network"? If the fault is supposed to be with your router, this has to work.

Comment: @Albin yes. private ip within internal work works fine. Also public ip from outside works fine.

Comment: Since access to the server from the outside work fine, I don't suspect the issue being with the port forward. What do the server and router logs say?

Comment: Router is ISP provided one. No way to access any logs. Nothing in server logs

Comment: What do the server logs say with a working connection (just to make sure)? How do you configure the router? Via Browser interface? Could be that it uses the port 443 for it's own web server if the connection is an internal one.

Comment: Also check the port via telnet and/or nmap and NC, a route trace might give you some information as well.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you ever find a solution or figure out what was causing this issue?

Comment: No. Moved to a different ISP/router. Don't have the problem anymore